# What is the performance of arbitrary ordering in PostgreSQL?

Tags: algorithm, postgresql, sorting, sql-order-by

In Postgres in is possible to perform an order like so

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE id in (8, 6, 7, 5, 10, 24)
ORDER BY id=8 DESC, id=6 DESC, id=7 DESC, id=5 DESC, id=10 DESC, id=24 DESC;
```

To select arbitrary data in arbitrary order.

I have figured that if some sorting algorithm has has O(log n), and we naively do an indexof sort like so:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return indexOf(a) < indexOf(b);
});
```

then we each sorting operation may take O(2n), making our total algorithmic time into O(n log n).

We can then create a simple index of values to positions instead of resorting each time. Assuming this has a worst time of O(log n) as well, we then get, for our sorting algorithm, O((log n)(log n)) or O((log n)^2). This is not great performance for an algorithm.

What algorithm, which what performance, does Postgres use? If it is better than O((log n) * the_sort_algorithms_performance), we will implement the sorting outside of the db. Alternatively, if the algorithm is one we easily can port to Java we may still not do the sorting in Postgres.

Comment: "psql" is the name of the command-line interface, and not a valid name for Postgres.

Comment: It seems like this would be fairly easy to determine through testing.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; Not going into details with your broad question. Sort algorithms are a complex field.

As for your **query**: if you provide a list of values, this can be considerably cheaper, because you have to pass the values in *some order* anyway:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   unnest('{8, 6, 7, 5, 10, 24}'::int[]) id
JOIN   mytable t USING (id);
```

This works, but there are no guarantees. To be sure (in Postgres 9.4+):

```
SELECT *
FROM   unnest('{8, 6, 7, 5, 10, 24}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY x(id, rn)
JOIN   mytable t USING (id)
ORDER  BY x.rn;
```

Details:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)